# How to implement a slice operator[] in C++?

Tags: c++, slice

This is probably a duplicate question but I can't seem to find the answer... I'm trying to implement a slicable container like object in C++ using the `operator[]`. Here's my implementation (which doesn't work):

```
class SlicableIntVector{
private:
    std::vector<int> vector;
public:
    explicit SlicableIntVector(std::vector<int> vector): vector(vector){};

    // The usual way of overloading operator[]
    int &operator[](int index){
        return vector[index];
    }
    // This version doesn't work as the argument is not binary
    int &operator[](int start, int end){
        return vector[vector.begin()+start, vector.begin()+start+end];
    }

    }
};
```

Other than just using another method to implement the slicing operation, what options do I have to get slicing working with `operator[]`? If I could get the flexibility of slicing like a python `list` I'd be happy.

Comment: Operator `[]` accepts only one argument by design. You may consider using `()` operator instead.

Comment: [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936399/c-array-operator-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: `int &operator[](int start, int end)` -- What were your intentions here?  What are you returning a reference to?  What you are looking for is equivalent to `std::string_view` or `std::span` (C ++20).  Also, trying to make C++ look like another language should be avoided.

Comment: The built in `std::list` has a [splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) method to move elements from one list to another.

Answer (score 2):

From `n4835`:

§12.6.2 **Binary operators**

> 1 A binary operator shall be implemented either by a non-static member function (11.4.1) with one parameter
>   or by a non-member function with two parameters

so you can't pass in two parameters.

So try something like:

```
int &operator[](std::tuple<int, int> start_end);
```