# How to overload [] to perform the task

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

```cpp
class matrix
{
    int r,c;
public:
    matrix(int r , int c)
    {
        this->r=r;
        this->c=c;
    }
};
```

I have this class named as `matrix`. Where I need to create a matrix by taking the size of the row and column and then `overload []` in such a way that when used with ob ( object of the matrix class)

like `ob[i][j]` to interchange the row and column of the matrix. (`i` size of column and `j` size of row)

How can I do the task?

Comment: You would need to do something like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969905/1960455) to the question [operator\[\]\[\] overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881)

Comment: [C++ \[\] array operator with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936399/c-array-operator-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: There are in general many ways how you could implement a matrix, and depending on that the solution how to implement that will vary.