# Overload the [] operator with pair<int, int> in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I want to overload a 2D vector's reference operator, [], with a pair of integers.
For example,
Consider a 2D vector of integers like this
v = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

`v[make_pair(1, 2)]`
Should return `6` at its at the 1st row and 2nd column (zero indexing).

Comment: Why? What is the actual problem that's supposed to solve? It's more to write than the standard `v[1][2]` (for a "2D" vector of vectors).

Comment: As for how to solve it: You can't. Not using standard `std::vector` anyway. The `operator[]` function must be a member function. Which means the only way to solve it is by making your own "2d vector" class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ \[\] array operator with multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936399/c-array-operator-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: You need to make your own 2D vector class. As for overloading the operators for element access, rather than overloading [] you should overload the call operator () and provide as many argument as you want. Then, you can access it as v(1, 2) rather than v[{1,2}].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm simulating a graph search, with a matrix of nodes and using pair<int, int> for the current coordinates. So doing graph[curr.first][curr.second] looked ugly and hence I was wondering if I could just do graph[curr]

Comment: You may define `operator[](const std::pair<int, int>&)` with your matrix class.